# How to create range filter using elaticsearch and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, filter, aggregation

I'm trying to add range aggregations to the runtime field for this rails app on this [link](https://github.com/zacksiri/moviedb):

**models/movie.rb:**

```
def custom_search(query_segment)
  keyword         = query_segment.delete("keyword")
  range_segments   = query_segment.delete("runtimes")
  filter_segments = query_segment

  __elasticsearch__.search(query:  MoviesQuery.build(keyword),
                           aggs:   MoviesQuery::Aggregate.build, 
                           filter: MoviesQuery::Filter.build(filter_segments, range_segments))
end
```

**movies_controller.rb**

```
def segmented_query
  query.slice(*["crews", "keyword", "genres", "runtimes"]) rescue {}
end
```

**movies_query.rb**

```
module Filter
  def self.build(segments, range)
    { 
      bool: { 
        must: nested_terms_filter(segments, range)
      }
    }
  end

  def self.nested_terms_filter(segments, range)
    segments.keys.map do |path|
      if path == "runtimes"
        if range.split("-").count > 1
          {
              "range": {
                  "runtime": {
                      "gt": range.split('-').first,
                      "lt": range.split('-').last
                  }
              }
          }
        else
          {
              "range": {
                  "runtime": {
                      "gt": range
                  }
              }
          }
        end
      else
        {
            nested: {
                path: path,
                filter: {
                    terms: { "#{path}.id": segments[path].split(',').map(&:to_i) }
                }
            }
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def agg_name(va)
    if va.first(2) == '*-'
      "#{va.split('-').last.to_i} and below"
    elsif va.last(2) == '-*'
      "above #{va.split('-').first.to_i}"
    else
      s = va.split('-')
      [s.first.to_i, s.last.to_i].join(' to ')
    end
  end

  def agg_id(va)
    if va.first(2) == '*-'
      "0-#{va.split('-').last.to_i}"
    elsif va.last(2) == '-*'
      "#{va.split('-').first.to_i}"
    else
      s = va.split('-')
      [s.first.to_i, s.last.to_i].join('-')
    end
  end
end
```

**presenter/aggregation_presenter.rb**

```
def buckets
  if aggregation[1].id_and_name.present?
    aggregation[1].id_and_name.buckets.map{ |b| BucketPresenter.new(b) }
  end
end
```

**views/aggregations/aggregation.html.haml**

```
%h3= agg.name
- if agg.buckets.present?
  %ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked
    - agg.buckets.each do |bucket|
      = content_tag :li, class: aggregation_active?(agg.kind, bucket.id) do
        = link_to aggregation_path(agg.kind, bucket.id, :merge) do
          = bucket.name
          (#{bucket.count})
- else
  %ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked
    - agg.aggregation[1]['buckets'].each do |bucket|
      = content_tag :li, class: aggregation_active?(agg.kind, agg_id(bucket['key']) ) do
        = link_to aggregation_path(agg.kind, agg_id(bucket['key']), :merge) do
          = agg_name(bucket['key'])
          (#{bucket.count})
```

passing this URL gives me:

***segments:***

```
{"crews"=>"44631,112041", "genres"=>"19,1"}
```

***range:***

```
"0-50,50-100"
```

Why is the range filter not working, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try using elasticsearch Sense to make the raw query work, it is easier from there. As soon as it works you will know how to generate it from ruby. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en

Comment: It looks like your issue is that you are not splitting on comma (`,`) to add _multiple_ filters. What happens if you just set the `range` as `0-50`? Unrelated to your issue, you should _not_ be using filter at the level you're using it because that's the [`post_filter`, which will not perform as well as putting it as part of the `query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/breaking_50_search_changes.html#_top_level_literal_filter_literal_parameter).